# A rational function with vanishing higher derivative is a polynomial

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Prove that if the $k$<sup>th</sup> derivative of a rational function $r(x)$ is zero for some $k$, then $r(x)$ is a polynomial.

I could not solve this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: May be start with $k=1$ and do induction.

Comment: If $f$ is a rational function that is not a polynomial, then $f(c)$ is not defined for some value $c$, and hence neither is the kth derivative at $c$, so the kth derivative isn't 0.   (Now, if you consider this solution a cop-out/stupid, you might want to say that the kth derivative is almost always 0.)

Comment: @CalvinLin kk ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the rational function is $h = p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomial functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (the domain of $h$ is the set $\mathbb{R}-\{\text{roots of q\}}$), with gcd($p,q$) = 1, deg$q$ > 0.

The first derivative of $h$ at a point $c$ is $\frac{p'(c)q(c)-p(c)q'(c)}{q(c)^2}$. Thus, the function $h'$ is given by $h'(c) =\frac{p'(c)q(c)-p(c)q'(c)}{q(c)^2}$ for all $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ which are not roots of $q$.

If you take the second derivative of $h$, you would get a rational function with a higher power in the denominator and which is nonzero. By induction, you can show that the kth derivative is not zero (which would be a contradiction). Hence, deg$q$=0 which means that $h$ is a polynomial function.

Comment: kk, thanks !!!!

Comment: I think you'd need further justification. For example, it is possible for the numerator of $h'$ to have common roots with the denominator, like when $q(x)$ has a double root, so we could reduce the power of the denominator. So, you'd still need to justify why the denominator of $h'$ is indeed higher than $h'$, as the degree need not double each time. (I agree that the denominator is indeed higher).

Comment: As an alternative, I believe what could be shown is that for a proper rational fraction, the  "degree of denominator - degree of numerator" increases by 1 with each derivative, so the degree of the denominator is never 0.